# Different types of linear solenoids

Tags: solenoid

I want to use a linear solenoid and there are different types, pull, push and pull/push.

So I chose a push solenoid for my application and saw the following picture.

[image]

I know that the plunger goes inside the body when energized the big axle (right) moves towards the body, and the small one (left) goes out of the body.

So why is there a mounting place on the big axle when it should be on the small one? (because this is a push type)

Or am I missing something? maybe I am confusing the different solenoid types?

Answer (score 0):

A solenoid with its axis sticking out at boths ends is usable as push or pull solenoid, no real difference. The direction *opposite* of the direction the spring extends is the one where you can actively exert force.

The picture that you show has a solenoid with a a tread on one side and something that looks convenient when you need to affix a rod or a pullstring on the other side. So, depending on which side you intend to use, it's a push, or a pull solenoid.